# split a string (R1) to char b='R' and int a=1

Tags: c

```
char **reg and lets say reg[0]="R1"
```

and

```
reg[1]="#-10"
```

and I want to split this strings something like that

```
char a='R',int b=1
```

and

```
char c='#'
```

and

```
int d=-10.
```

I did not find anything. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Which standard functions have you looked at that involve parsing strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this, I assume there is a single char.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *reg = "R1";
    char *rog = "#-10";
    char c;
    int i;

    sscanf(reg, "%c%d", &c, &i);
    printf("%c %d\n", c, i);

    sscanf(rog, "%c%d", &c, &i);
    printf("%c %d\n", c, i);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
R 1
# -10
```

I leave the string array to you.